# documentclass{book} + mdframed + leftmargin

Tags: mdframed

My problem is when I use documentclass{book} leftmargin and rightmargin has no reaction, but It works with documentclass{article}. How I can fix this? I have to use documentclass{book}.

```
enter code here\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray, leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,roundcorner=8pt]
```

Comment: Please post a full , minimal compilable example such that we do not have to guess about the rest of the document.

Comment: Include `\documentclass`, `\usepackage{}` and `\end{document}` commands in your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 3):

Book is twosided, so in that case what is left and right? especially when they have different values.

See the section 6.7 in the `mdframed` manual. This works

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mdframed,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mdframed}[innermargin=3cm,outermargin=1cm]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```